# Kill all program.exe instances open on network share from Windows

Tags: windows, kill, application, open

How do I kill all `program.exe` instances that are currently open through a Windows network share?

I know how to list the open files `net files | Findstr "program.exe"` but how then how do I kill it?

In Linux I would type:

```
kill -9 `pidof program.exe`
```

What is the equivalent of this in Windows?

Comment: Windows Samba ? ...

Comment: Windows Share ( SMB )

Comment: `net files` shows you files that are open on your machine *from other peoples computers*. Do you want to kill the process on the remote machine? If so, then we'll need to know what versions of Windows they're running.

Answer (score 2):

If your windows version has powershell (if not, you can download and install from microsoft site), it is very easy as well

```
get-process "program.exe" | stop-process -force -confirm:$false
```

Comment: You writing about system processes, but i'm looking for open network files ( look at: net files ) :)

Comment: oh sorry i thought you were asking for processes. net file filenum /close is what you are looking for then? where filenum is what you find in the net files listing.

Comment: True, net file /close is what i am looking for, i wrote it in 1st post ;) 

But i don't know how to connect it with findstring and kill PID's only from program: sample.exe ;) 

So: I need to do one command and kill all PID's from files example.exe :)

Comment: i don't think there is a such a command, but there might be batch files or powershells scripts available, or you can write one. if you have powershell, i can likely whip up one for you quickly if you cannot write one quickly and cannot find one written by someone else, but not batch file, as i am really rusty in batch files by now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290585/en-us

I believe this still applies to current Windows versions, or should at least put you in the right direction.

Command line:

```
for /f "skip=4 tokens=1" %a in ('net files') do net files %a /close
```

Batch file:

```
for /f "skip=4 tokens=1" %%a in ('net files') do net files %%a /close
```

Answer (score 0):

tskill.exe (either built-in or possibly in a resource kit) or pskill.exe, from sysinternals - which as a Windows admin, you should have on a USB key and on a network share.

Also, don't forget to include which version of Windows you're working on - that may make a difference with someone's answer - although likely not for this question.